# How to construct a "leading" equivalent to FollowedBy subclass in PyParsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to clean out some code by removing either leading or trailing white space characters using PyParsing. Removing leading white spaces was quite easy as I could make use of the `FollowedBy` subclass which matches a string but does not include it. Now I would need the same for something that follows my identifying string.

Here a small example:

```
from pyparsing import *

insource = """
annotation (Documentation(info="  
  <html>  
<b>FOO</b>
</html>  
 "));
"""
# Working replacement:
HTMLStartref = OneOrMore(White(' \t\n')) + (FollowedBy(CaselessLiteral('<html>')))

## Not working because of non-existing "LeadBy" 
# HTMLEndref = LeadBy(CaselessLiteral('</html>')) + OneOrMore(White(' \t\n')) + FollowedBy('"')

out = Suppress(HTMLStartref).transformString(insource)
out2 = Suppress(HTMLEndref).transformString(out)
```

As output one gets:

```
>>> print out
annotation (Documentation(info="<html>
<b>FOO</b>
</html>
 "));
```

and **should** get:

```
>>> print out2
annotation (Documentation(info="<html>
<b>FOO</b>
</html>"));
```

I looked at the [documentation](http://pyparsing.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pyparsing/src/HowToUsePyparsing.html) but could not find a "`LeadBy`" equivalent to `FollowedBy` or a way how to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is something like "lookbehind", that is, match only if something is preceded by a particular pattern.  I don't really have an explicit class for that at the moment, but for what you want to do, you can still transform left-to-right, and just leave in the leading part, and not suppress it, just suppress the whitespace.

Here are a couple of ways to address your problem:

```
# define expressions to match leading and trailing
# html tags, and just suppress the leading or trailing whitespace
opener = White().suppress() + Literal("<html>")
closer = Literal("</html>") + White().suppress()

# define a single expression to match either opener
# or closer - have to add leaveWhitespace() call so that
# we catch the leading whitespace in opener
either = opener|closer
either.leaveWhitespace()

print either.transformString(insource) 


# alternative, if you know what the tag will look like:
# match 'info=<some double quoted string>', and use a parse
# action to extract the contents within the quoted string,
# call strip() to remove leading and trailing whitespace,
# and then restore the original '"' characters (which are
# auto-stripped by the QuotedString class by default)
infovalue = QuotedString('"', multiline=True)
infovalue.setParseAction(lambda t: '"' + t[0].strip() + '"')
infoattr = "info=" + infovalue

print infoattr.transformString(insource)
```

Comment: Thanks Paul! That was exactly what I was looking for. Due to more complexity issues I'll stick to the first solution (although I really like the second implementation and try to remember that one).